new hxsj keyboard rgb and key remap
i have bought a new keyboard which i am sort of unable to understand its the hxsj v200 the thing is that the rgb isnt working and if i press some function keys the keys are getting remapped for instance the wasd turning into arrow keys, my question would be if there is a better manual than the one in the box and if there is a generic software to remap rgb of cheap chinese keyboards like this one

As you state, the manual at https://device.report/manual/9776369 is minimal: " FN+W: W.A S.D key and arrow key switching function," or "FN + up arrow key and FN + down arrow key to adjust backlight brightness," as is that at https://manuals.plus/m/4b5f772803a6b82536c5216e80b6547e13293df7d38daad97717b7c1343a2eed

Yes thank you. But the thing is rgb still refuses to turn on
